# Are the terms "Coupled approach" and "Hand flown approach" strictly defined?

Tags: landing, instrument-flight-rules, approach, autopilot, logging

I was looking on SE and also Google for the answer, but couldn't find anything. My question is when to log an approach as coupled or handflown? All of the approaches I fly are CAT I but the aircraft's autopilot has a coupled approach mode

Comment: Why would you need to ***log*** an approach as one or the other? Either way, you flew the approach. If one or the other is needed to meet some requirement, then read the wording of that requirement.  But other than a **small** handful of very specialized situations (which specify clearly what's required), I can't recall any general requirement for logging an approach as coupled or hand-flown.

Comment: @RalphJ some carriers require hand flying approaches occasionally to maintain skills, and presumably they'd want that logged to determine compliance.

Comment: @StephenSprunk In that case, each of those carriers would define what they consider to be “hand flown” — FAF to DA, 1000’ to DA, whatever.  There is no single “strictly defined” that necessarily applies in all cases.